# Can't decrypt OpenPGP data I encrypt with BouncyCastle C#

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, pgp

I'm trying to encrypt strings (not files) with OpenPGP using BouncyCastle. I generated a public/private key pair using GPG4win (Kleopatra) for testing. My code works, and outputs the encrypted file, however I cannot decrypt that file again with Kleopatra. I get a message: "Could not determine whether this is an OpenPGP or S/MIME signature - maybe it is not a signature at all?".

Here is the code I use to encrypt the file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Org.BouncyCastle;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp;
namespace RXNet
{
public static class Encrypter //Inspired by http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/kim/archive/2009/01/23/pgp-zip-encrypted-files-with-c.aspx
{
    private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1 << 16;
    public static string EncryptPackAndBase64(string strdata, string keyString)
    {
        if (strdata.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("A blank string was provided.");
        //Extract the key from PGP format
        PgpPublicKey enckey = readPublicKeyFromString(keyString);


        Stream outputStream = new MemoryStream(); 
        MemoryStream dataStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strdata));

        using (Stream encryptedOut = ChainEncryptedOut(outputStream, enckey))
        using (Stream compressedOut = ChainCompressedOut(encryptedOut))
        {

            //PgpSignatureGenerator signatureGenerator = InitSignatureGenerator(compressedOut);

            using (Stream literalOut = ChainLiteralOut(compressedOut, dataStream.Length))
            {
                WriteOutput(literalOut, dataStream);
            }
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(((MemoryStream)outputStream).ToArray());
        }





    }

    private static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            input.CopyTo(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    private static PgpPublicKey readPublicKeyFromString(string base64str)
    {
        byte[] key = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64str);
        using (Stream keyIn = new MemoryStream(key))
        using (Stream inputStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(keyIn))
        {

            PgpPublicKeyRingBundle publicKeyRingBundle = new PgpPublicKeyRingBundle(inputStream);

            PgpPublicKey foundKey = getFirstPublicKey(publicKeyRingBundle);

            if (foundKey != null)
                return foundKey;

        }

        throw new ArgumentException("No encryption key found in public key ring.");
    }

    private static PgpPublicKey getFirstPublicKey(PgpPublicKeyRingBundle publicKeyRingBundle)
    {

        foreach (PgpPublicKeyRing kRing in publicKeyRingBundle.GetKeyRings())
        {

            PgpPublicKey key = kRing.GetPublicKeys()
                .Cast<PgpPublicKey>()
                .Where(k => k.IsEncryptionKey)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (key != null)
                return key;

        }

        return null;

    }

    private static Stream ChainCompressedOut(Stream encryptedOut)
    {

        PgpCompressedDataGenerator compressedDataGenerator =

            new PgpCompressedDataGenerator(CompressionAlgorithmTag.Zip);

        return compressedDataGenerator.Open(encryptedOut);

    }

    private static Stream ChainEncryptedOut(Stream outputStream, PgpPublicKey key)
    {

        PgpEncryptedDataGenerator encryptedDataGenerator;

        encryptedDataGenerator =

            new PgpEncryptedDataGenerator(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.Cast5, new SecureRandom());

        encryptedDataGenerator.AddMethod(key);

        return encryptedDataGenerator.Open(outputStream, new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]);

    }

    private static Stream ChainLiteralOut(Stream compressedOut, long length)
    {

        PgpLiteralDataGenerator pgpLiteralDataGenerator = new PgpLiteralDataGenerator();

        return pgpLiteralDataGenerator.Open(compressedOut, PgpLiteralData.Binary, PgpLiteralData.Console, length, DateTime.Now);

    }

    private static void WriteOutput(Stream literalOut, Stream inputStream)
    {

        int length = 0;

        byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        while ((length = inputStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
        {

            literalOut.Write(buf, 0, length);

        }


    }
}
}
```

I then call it as follows:

```
string encc = Encrypter.EncryptPackAndBase64("Test 123 123 123", @"mQENBFEznzsBCADIg9CTEJygWls+b+pGqFcD9rx8XjGfo9l513Av0GpDKuCEaP+Dq4A1wox3RcK/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=");
            FileStream st = new FileStream(@"D:\enc.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            var b = Convert.FromBase64String(encc);
            st.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            st.Close();
```

In the full environments, I will be getting the keys as Base64 strings, so that's the reason I'm passing it in like that. I tried to use the armored version of the key, but it didn't work; This is the binary version that I Base64'd manually.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error while verifying files encrypted via Bouncy Castle in [Kleopatra](http://www.gpg4win.org/).

Resolution for me was to rename the encrypted file with a `.gpg` extension.